# Calling the available networks dialog in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, shell, windows-runtime

I'm using a custom shell application and I'm attempting to call the view available networks dialog box in windows 8, I have a working example for windows 7. The bar in question is the black bar that flies in when you execute:

```
rundll32 van.dll RunVAN
```

When using a custom shell with windows 7, it was previously necessary to call RUNVANUI first before you could call RunVAN.

With windows 8 and above this entrypoint (RunVANUI) is no longer available and when you run the above command the dialog does not appear.

I was hoping somebody might know the trick to call this function or if you could point me in the right direction for finding the neccessary steps to call runVAN within a custom shell on windows 8.

Comment: RunVanUI seems to be available on W8 : http://www.nirsoft.net/dll_information/windows8/van_dll.html